# Como dar um echo no modalidade?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Planos] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 57
                    [nome] => test
                    [descricao] => test
                    [valor] => 1.00
                    [status] => 0
                    [id_aluno] => 1
                )

            [Alunos] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [nome] => Flávio
                    [telefone] => 155
                    [email] => flavio@flavio
                    [data_nascimento] => 1996-12-08
                    [sexo] => M
                    [endereco] => testando
                    [cpf] => 123
                    [rg] => 123
                )

            [Modalidades] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [modalidade] => MMA
                            [ModalidadesPlano] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [id_plano] => 57
                                    [id_modalidade] => 4
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [modalidade] => Zumba
                            [ModalidadesPlano] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [id_plano] => 57
                                    [id_modalidade] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

No seu exemplo seria algo como:

```
$modalidades = $array[0]['modalidades'];

foreach($modalidades as $key => $value){
    echo $value['modalidade'] . "\n";
}
```

Isso imprimirá

> MMA
>
> ZUMBA

Comment: Consegui aqui obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não está muito coerente, pois existem duas chaves com o nome "modalidade", além disso, você não especificou se quer imprimir o valor ou a chave, mas se teu desejo é pegar o primeiro valor das modalidades, onde tem uma chave modalidade, seria assim:

```
$seuArray[0]['Modalidades'][0]['modalidade'];
echo $seuArray;
```

[**Exemplo no IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/bR60bn)

Comment: Consegui aqui obrigado